# Crash using QFuture with QML

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qml

I'm trying to create a simple `Task` class that will be exposed to QML to do asynchronous operations in C++. To do this, I want to avoid subclassing `QObject` and instead I'm using the `Q_GADGET` macro as follows:

```
#pragma once
#include <QFuture>

// Workaround to use a templated class with Q_GADGET
class TaskBase {
    Q_GADGET
};

template <typename T>
class Task : public TaskBase
{
public:
    explicit Task() {}
    // Creates a task from a QFuture
    explicit Task(QFuture<T> future) : m_future(future)
    {
        auto watcher = new QFutureWatcher<T>();

        QObject::connect(watcher, &QFutureWatcher<T>::finished, [this, watcher](){
            qDebug () << "Finished, result is" << result();
            watcher->deleteLater();
        });
        watcher->setFuture(future);
    }

    // Returns the result of the task
    Q_INVOKABLE T result() { return m_future.result(); }


private:
    QFuture<T> m_future;
};

// Register classes to QML
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(Task<qint64>)
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(Task<QString>)
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(Task<bool>)
```

Then I'm using the class as follows:

```
// main.cpp
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QtConcurrent>

#include "task.h"


class HeavyComputer : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    HeavyComputer(QObject *parent = nullptr) : QObject(parent) {}

    Q_INVOKABLE Task<qint64> compute() const
    {
        return Task<qint64>(QtConcurrent::run([](){
            qint64 sum  = 0;
            for(int i = 0; i < 100000; ++i){
                sum += i;
            }
            return sum;
        }));
    }
};


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    qRegisterMetaType<Task<qint64>>();

    // Create a QML engine.
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

    // Register the HeavyComputer class
    qmlRegisterType<HeavyComputer>("HeavyComputer", 1, 0, "HeavyComputer");

    // Load the QML file.
    const QUrl url(QStringLiteral("qrc:/qml/main.qml"));
    QObject::connect(
        &engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated,
        &app, [url](QObject *obj, const QUrl &objUrl)
        {
        if (!obj && url == objUrl)
            QCoreApplication::exit(-1); },
        Qt::QueuedConnection);
    engine.load(url);

    // Return the application's exit code.s
    return app.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

Using it from QML:

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15
import HeavyComputer 1.0

Window {
    id: window
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    HeavyComputer {
        id: computer
    }

    Button {
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        text: "Compute"
        onClicked: {
            computer.compute()
        }
    }
}
```

Now unfortunately, if you run the example and click on the button multiple times the application crashes. The debugger points out that the problem is in this line due a write access violation:

```
            qDebug () << "Finished, result is" << result();
```

The stack information says this:

```
1   std::_Atomic_storage<QMutexData *,8>::compare_exchange_strong                                                           atomic                 737  0x7ffb1d1ddec2 
2   std::atomic<QMutexData *>::compare_exchange_strong                                                                      atomic                 1600 0x7ffb1d1ddfcc 
3   QAtomicOps<QMutexData *>::testAndSetAcquire<QMutexData *>                                                               qatomic_cxx11.h        308  0x7ffb1d1d985a 
4   QBasicAtomicPointer<QMutexData>::testAndSetAcquire                                                                      qbasicatomic.h         273  0x7ffb1d1e8354 
5   QBasicMutex::fastTryLock                                                                                                qmutex.h               109  0x7ffb1d1df761 
6   QMutex::lock                                                                                                            qmutex.cpp             230  0x7ffb1d21fb28 
7   QMutexLocker::QMutexLocker                                                                                              qmutex.h               234  0x7ffb1d1da5bd 
8   QFutureInterfaceBase::waitForResult                                                                                     qfutureinterface.cpp   317  0x7ffb1d236099 
9   QFuture<__int64>::result                                                                                                qfuture.h              209  0x7ff7aba58421 
10  Task<__int64>::result                                                                                                   task.h                 27   0x7ff7aba58467 
11  <lambda_37427196d3c8e94283745470a735a1b5>::operator()                                                                   task.h                 20   0x7ff7aba56ce1 
12  QtPrivate::FunctorCall<QtPrivate::IndexesList<>,QtPrivate::List<>,void,<lambda_37427196d3c8e94283745470a735a1b5>>::call qobjectdefs_impl.h     146  0x7ff7aba575d9 
13  QtPrivate::Functor<<lambda_37427196d3c8e94283745470a735a1b5>,0>::call<QtPrivate::List<>,void>                           qobjectdefs_impl.h     257  0x7ff7aba53e43 
14  QtPrivate::QFunctorSlotObject<<lambda_37427196d3c8e94283745470a735a1b5>,0,QtPrivate::List<>,void>::impl                 qobjectdefs_impl.h     449  0x7ff7aba57d4e 
15  QtPrivate::QSlotObjectBase::call                                                                                        qobjectdefs_impl.h     398  0x7ffb1d64e9d2 
16  doActivate<0>                                                                                                           qobject.cpp            3886 0x7ffb1d6a6bb8 
17  QMetaObject::activate                                                                                                   qobject.cpp            3947 0x7ffb1d6936d7 
18  QFutureWatcherBase::finished                                                                                            moc_qfuturewatcher.cpp 274  0x7ffb1d23a5f3 
19  QFutureWatcherBasePrivate::sendCallOutEvent                                                                             qfuturewatcher.cpp     442  0x7ffb1d23af0e 
20  QFutureWatcherBase::event                                                                                               qfuturewatcher.cpp     336  0x7ffb1d23a581 
... <More>
```

EDIT: the problem also only occurs if `HeavyComputer::compute()` is called from QML. Doing this in C++:

```
HeavyComputer computer;
computer.compute();
```

works just fine with no crashes.

Comment: Have you looked at https://github.com/benlau/quickfuture ?

Comment: This is not needed. You need to pass parameters through the invokable method from QML: ```// Register classes to QML
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(Task<qint64>)
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(Task<QString>)
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(Task<bool>)```

Comment: I do something like `auto future = QtConcurrent::run(  [this](){computation();} )` and then `QFutureWatcher<void> watcher; watcher.setFuture(future); watcher.waitForFinished()` when synchronization needed to make tasks complete. Of course this only makes sense when there many tasks in parallel. Otherwise the worker thread will do. Mind to collect features to `QList` or vector and iteratively put them to watcher.

Comment: @GrecKo Thanks I'll check it out and see if it works for my usecase (note that above is just a MRE and my real program needs to handle a more complex situation).

Comment: @AlexanderV What do you mean that the `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE` calls aren't necessary? They are necessary if I want to access the `Task` instance's properties from QML. Also for my needs, I don't want to every block the calling thread so waitForFinished is not an option

Comment: @devinbed Accessing those types immediately from QML is not a good design. Just pass the data for calculation through that invokable function parameters. And I guess you need add a property `result` and a change signal for that property instead of result() call.

Comment: @AlexanderV Why is it not a good design? Having QFuture easily accessible from QML makes a lot of sense. It can't be mapped all the time to a property + signal, for example if you run concurrent tasks. That's why project like the one I linked or suggestions like this one https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-101025 are made.

Comment: @devinbed Only HeavyComputer is registered for QML. Those registered as Qt meta types and not even registered for QML yet. Then I do not know why. Try. Did you try to access that QFuture<Task> or 3 Task C++ template specializations from QML? When you try then see what can you do with that? I do create types in C++ accessible in QML. Never like that.